# Hyperledger Fabric error when creating a peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have set up my core.yaml to use the CouchDB instance on the same node as the peer, I am not using docker but directly the peer command on the node.

While running the peer node start for the first time, I get the following error:

```
[36m2020-09-03 17:35:35.619 UTC [kvledger] recoverUnderConstructionLedger -> DEBU 083[0m Recovering under construction ledger
[36m2020-09-03 17:35:35.619 UTC [kvledger] recoverUnderConstructionLedger -> DEBU 084[0m No under construction ledger found. Quitting recovery

panic: Error in instantiating ledger provider: sync /vagrant/runtime/peer0/ledger/ledgersData/snapshots: invalid argument
error while synching dir:/vagrant/runtime/peer0/ledger/ledgersData/snapshots

github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.syncDir
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/snapshot.go:186
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.(*Provider).initSnapshotDir
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/kv_ledger_provider.go:266
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.NewProvider
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/kv_ledger_provider.go:132
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.NewLedgerMgr
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:65
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.serve
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/start.go:426
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.glob..func6
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/start.go:127
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800
main.main
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/peer/main.go:54
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.NewLedgerMgr(0xc000367968, 0x1b0d960)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:79 +0x782
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.serve(0x24a9520, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/start.go:426 +0x1f62
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.glob..func6(0x2377120, 0x24a9520, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/start.go:127 +0x9c
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x2377120, 0x24a9520, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2377120, 0x24a9520)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762 +0x453
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x2377840, 0xc0005a5f50, 0x1, 0x1)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852 +0x2ea
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800
main.main()
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/peer/main.go:54 +0x45b
```

I searched around but it seems there is not much reference to this particular error.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The usual vagrant problem with synced directories in the host (e.g.
https://medium.com/@dtinth/isolating-node-modules-in-vagrant-9e646067b36)

I just had to mount with binding the /vagrant/runtime to $HOME/runtime and the node was starting just fine.

Comment: That would be it, and just an FYI for anyone else who might read this, you weren't able to search this error specifically, because the directory it was mounting is brand new, its part of a feature we are working on for snapshotting your ledger so new peers can join channels without having to sync blocks, so there aren't a lot of hits on this directory yet on search engines. But glad you were able to resolve this :)